# Spring resource mapping not working with localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, localhost

**Setup**

servlet-context.xml

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/test.js"></script>
```

file location

```
webapp/resources/js/test.js
```

**Problem**

When I access `localhost:8080/myApp/resources/js/test.js` it is found but what is actually rendered in the page is `localhost:8080/resources/js/test.js` so `/myApp` is missing.

Is this really the case for localhost or is there something wrong with my setup?

This is a fresh Spring MVC Project made using STS (template) so I doubt it's the setup because it's already there from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the context path when declaring the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.ContextPath}/resources/js/test.js"></script>
```

Assuming the script is declared in your jsp page. The context path points to the root of your app.

Comment: even better use the spring url tag for this.